# Response is not declared in VB.NET for iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I'm currently developing a automated voting system. As of now we are planning some archive features in our system by creating pdf file of the election result. I'm trying to implement this lines of code in my system:

```
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=student.pdf")
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Dim StringWriter1 As New StringWriter() 
    Dim HtmlTextWriter1 As New HtmlTextWriter(StringWriter1)
    GridView1.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter1)
    Dim StringReader1 As New StringReader(StringWriter1.ToString())
    Dim newDocument As New Document(PageSize.A4, 7.0F, 7.0F, 7.0F, 7.0F)
    Dim HTMLWorker1 As New HTMLWorker(newDocument)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(newDocument, Response.OutputStream)
    newDocument.Open()
    HTMLWorker1.Parse(StringReader1)
    newDocument.Close()
    Response.Write(newDocument)
    Response.End()
```

But for some reason the method "Response" is not recognize by the IDE.
I already import the following:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.html
Imports iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser
```

Comment: The Response object *usually* refers to the context of an asp.net-based web page. Is this the case for you?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you lack of the following line of code under Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=student.pdf"):
Response.TransmitFile(MapPath("PDF\" & "temp" & ".pdf"))